# Is it safe to use multiple ScanFilters with BluetoothLeScanner?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

Our Android app uses `BluetoothLeScanner.startScan()` to scan for a single GATT Service UUID using a single `ScanFilter` today. We are now about to update the app to scan for *multiple* UUIDs by using multiple `ScanFilter`s, one per UUID.

According to the docs this should work just fine and we also didn't experience any issues when testing on some recent phones so far. However, it's known, that the Bluetooth stack differs significantly among different Android phones (vendors, models, versions) and that it's sometimes quite bugy, especially on older phones. So my question is: How likely is it, that the intended change will cause problems on any devices that successfully run our app today? Will we have to expect, that scanning for BLE devices will stop working on any of our customers phones? Are there any known issues? I'm aware, that it might not be possible to give a reasonable answer for devices running custom ROMs, but what about the broad majority of phones running official ROMs?

We're supporting Android devices with API level >= 21.